# how to use two different jquery version same time. my codes are not working properly with two different jquery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I got some jquery codes from my affiliate providers. codes are below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```

I have to assign above codes with my form which is below :

```
 1. html>    <body>    <form action="http://flights.tripguruji.com/"
    method="GET">
         <table>
           <tr><th>From</th><td><input type="text" id="a1" name="a1"/></td></tr>
           <tr><th>To</th><td><input type="text" id="a2" name="a2"/></td></tr>
           <tr><th>Depart</th><td><input type="text" id="d1" name="d1"/></td></tr>
           <tr><th>Return</th><td><input type="text" id="d2" name="d2"/></td></tr>
          </table>
        </form> </body> </html>
```

Form is not being pasted here properly. I tell you:

1. a1 - from (airport)
2. a2- to (airport)
3. d1- depart date
4. d2- return date

This is all my form is containing.

I also have to use jquery for collapsible menu for mobile view. But both are not working together. I need to disable either Google jquery CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or my own hosted jquery link.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me how to use both any other idea?

Comment: It would be a better use of your time to fix the code that doesn't work in the new version. Running multiple versions of jQuery just brings a separate set of problems.

Comment: Why are you using 2 different versions in the first place?

Comment: Try using jQuery Migrate https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI provided in the affiliate code is old. Try to replace it with a current version - see below - and use your own 1.12-jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
```